# Dot function for android calculator

Tags: java, android

I am not able to figure out a way to find a method to implement all the possibilities to put a dot for decimal representation of numbers

The calculator has only 1 text Field (editText) which computes the values as soon as there are 2 operators the first part is solved and appends the operator

some thing i tried...

```
    public void dot(View v) {
    if(count==1)
    {
        EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String input=et.getText().toString();
        String[] parts=input.split("[+ - * /]");
        if(parts[4].matches("[.]")){
            return;
        }
        else{
            et.append(".");
        }
    }
    else{
        EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String input=et.getText().toString();
        if(input.matches("[.]"))
            return;
        else{
            if(input.length()==0)
                et.append("0");
            et.append(".");
        }
    }

}
```

`count` keeps track of number of operators `{values(0,1)}`

Comment: count keeps track of number of operators

Comment: I'm confused what you want the dot function to do

Comment: Do you mean two *operands*?

Comment: By the way, the regex only needs to be `"[+-*/ ]"`

Comment: the dot functions adds a period after number if it is valid for decimal representation

Comment: I think your problem is that `.` in REGEX means "any character", and to escape that out from Java you need to use `\\.`

Comment: This entire method doesn't seem to be working i will rewrite this any suggestions on how to get decimal at right position in calculator program

Comment: Thanks EpicPandaForce, cricket_007 for regex fix and all others for help